# Couch DB installation not working on Mac OSx Lion

Tags: macos, installation, couchdb

I had a problem installing Couch DB on mac OSx Lion using Homebrew.
I execute the command

```
brew install couchdb
```

but then I have have a problem with mmd5 on file
`~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/spidermonkey-1.8.5.tar.gz`

How can I proceed?

Comment: You should restructure this as a question, and then an answer.  Answering your own questions is encouraged on SO.

Comment: Agreed, you should really rephrase this as a question, but regardless this is a good answer.

Comment: You need to move your update as an answer and remove it from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I found out how to fix the problem:

you have to remove the file

```
rm ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/spidermonkey-1.8.5.tar.gz
```

and update your Homebrew by running

```
brew update
```

you might have git problem here (as I had) to resolve it reset all local homebrew changes by running

```
git reset --hard
git clean -f -x -d
```

and run

```
brew update
```

and now it should be straight forward to install couchdb

```
brew install couchdb
```

(if you are running LION):

```
brew install -v couchdb
```

to runn it type

```
couchdb
```