# Where is the download for mac osx on couchdb.org?

Tags: macos, installation, osx-lion, couchdb

I upgraded my OSX to Lion.  As I went to install couchdb locally I found that the installer link for mac on [http://couchdb.apache.org](http://couchdb.apache.org/) was gone and replaced with "Mac OS X binaries coming soon".  I haven't used couchdb before but I know it was there at one point.

A friend sent me a copy zipped up which he installed on his Snow Leopard OSX.  This installed and I could access the Admin Console, but I was unable to access futon.

Is there a reason the button is missing, or is there another way to install it?

Comment: It's gone because they have just released 1.2.1 and `.dmg` is still not available. The one that you probably had in your previous version of OSX was the 1.2(.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version 1.2.1 has recently been released and packed for Mac OSX. You can download it from http://couchdb.apache.org/#download or from http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/couchdb/packages/mac/1.2.1/Apache-CouchDB-1.2.1.zip

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the site is detecting my operating system and they just aren't ready for 10.7.5  yet. But How do I go about installing a local version?

To install I followed the steps in this post [Couch DB installation not working on Mac OSx Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282638/couch-db-installation-on-mac-osx-lion).

It worked like a charm step by step.